# Differentiate the parametric function and find $dy/dx$ and $d^2y/dx^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parametric

Differentiate the parametric function and find $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ and $\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}$ in terms of "$t$" when:

$ x =  \frac{1}{t-1}$ and $y = \frac{1}{t+1}$

I have first started by finding $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ by finding $\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}$ and $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}$ which comes to

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=\ln |t-1|$$ and $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}=\ln |t+1|$$

and used $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} =\frac{\mathrm dy/\mathrm dt}{\mathrm  dx/\mathrm dt} $ ,which gives

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\ln|t+1|}{\ln|t-1|}$$ now if I divide them by each other doesn't it equal to $0$? What have I done wrong here?

Comment: Try not to use displayed equations unless it is a complicated or important one. It is 10 times harder to read.

Comment: think that should help

Comment: Uh no I meant don't use `$$...$$` that forces the equation to be all by itself on a new line. Display style or inline style doesn't make much difference, but if one has to read an equation followed by one or two words then another equation then another one or two words and so on, it's troublesome.

Comment: got you now. sorry lol

Comment: By the way `\ln` will get you the upright log function.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dy}=1$

Comment: And are $x$ and $X$ and $y$ and $Y$ different?

Comment: this has been fixed

Comment: I am very bad at this math jax. allow me

Answer (score 0):

Given $$\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{t-1}.$$ So $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{1}{(t-1)}$ and $$\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{t+1}$$ So $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = -\frac{1}{(t+1)}$

Now $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x} = 2\;,$$ Now Diff. both side w. r to $x$

$$\displaystyle -\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{1}{x^2} = 0\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2}{x^2}$$

Now Again Diff. w. r to $x\;,$ We get

$$\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right] = \frac{x^2\cdot 2y\frac{dy}{dx}-y^2 \cdot 2x}{x^4} = \frac{2y^3-2xy^2}{x^4}$$

Above we have put value f $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y^2}{x^2}$
So we get $$\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{2y^3-2xy^2}{x^4}$$

Comment: so does this express them in terms of 't'?

Comment: & isn't the differential of 1/(x) = lnx?

Comment: Put value of $x$ and y in $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$

Comment: No $\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x}dx = \ln |x|$ It is Integration.

Comment: oh yeah, apologies. how do you know dx/dt and dy/dt change it to a minus?

Comment: there is no value of x/y, they are being expressed as a function of t

Comment: @juantheron $$x = \frac{1}{t-1} \implies x' = \frac{-1}{(t-1)^2}$$

Similarly for the $y$ case..

Answer (score 0):

Given $\displaystyle x = \frac{1}{t-1}$ and $\displaystyle y = \frac{1}{t+1}$

the differentiation of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$

here $ x= \frac{1}{t-1} = (t-1)^{-1}$

So $ \frac{dx}{dt}= \frac{d(t-1)^{-1}}{dt}$

$= \frac{d(t-1)^{-1}}{d(t-1)} . \frac{d(t-1)}{dt}$
$=(-1)(t-1)^{-1-1}.(1)$
$=-(t-1)^{-2}$
$=\frac{-1}{(t-1)^{2}}$

Similarly you can do with Y and then for $dx^{2}$ and $dy^{2}$

Comment: I think you mean

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{-1}{(t-1)^2}$$